# Determine if Window is Open Using UIAutomation

Tags: excel, vba, ui-automation

I am writing an excel plugin that outputs an edge list and a graphml sheet that are later used by the program yED to make a bitmap of the graph for the overall output of the plugin. I am using a shell command to open the appropriate file in yED, and UIAutomation to send the commands to yED.

When there is a window of yED already open, the code executes just fine. The window is found by the polling, then set active and the commands sent over. Where it goes wrong is when the shell command causes a new window of yED to be launched. There is a splash screen for yED as it is loading in that takes a few seconds to get through, and shares the same Name and Class as the window that I am looking for. The HWND is different between the two.

My code will error out whenever there is a new window of yED launching. The error reads:

> Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': Automation error Unspecified
>   error

Reference code:

```
Function FindyEdByClass() As IUIAutomationElement
    Dim oUIAutomation As New CUIAutomation
    Dim oUIADesktop As IUIAutomationElement
    Dim allChilds As IUIAutomationElementArray
    Dim oUIAyED As IUIAutomationElement
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Timer As Date

    Set oUIADesktop = oUIAutomation.GetRootElement
    Set oUIAyED = oUIADesktop
    Timer = Now
RestartLoop:
    Set allChilds = oUIADesktop.FindAll(TreeScope_Children, oUIAutomation.CreateTrueCondition)
    Debug.Print "StartLoop" & vbCrLf;
    For i = 0 To allChilds.Length - 1
        'EDIT: the following line is the one that errors out.
        If allChilds.GetElement(i).CurrentName = "Graph.graphml - yEd" And allChilds.GetElement(i).CurrentClassName = "SunAwtFrame" Then
            Debug.Print "Found Child - yED" & vbCrLf;
            Set oUIAyED = allChilds.GetElement(i)
        End If
    Next
    If Now() > (Timer + TimeValue("00:00:10")) Then GoTo NoyED
    If oUIAyED.CurrentName = "Desktop" Then GoTo RestartLoop
EndOFLoop:
    Debug.Print oUIAyED.CurrentName & " " & oUIAyED.CurrentClassName & vbCrLf;
    Set FindyEdByClass = oUIAyED
Exit Function
NoyED:
    MsgBox "No yED Window Found"
    End
End Function
```

The line it errors out on the If statement. Through use of Debug.Print and FindWindowEx I have discovered that the object it errors out on is not the yED window I am looking for, but the yED splash screen that precedes it. I assume that the error is caused by the splash screen disappearing after its load time is up.

How do I go about finding the window I am looking for in this case? I need to be able to find the window without seeing the splash screen that will cause the error, and I need to be able to differentiate between the two by something other than class or name.

Note: I want to compare the windows by HWND but I don't know how to find it without the class/name, and it is never the same between two runs.

Comment: Which line? Can you point out that?

Comment: Ill edit in a comment above it right now.

Comment: Did the below solution worked for you?

Comment: Sorry, I was in a meeting. And it throws a type mismatch error on the same line when the `And` is replaced with `&`

Comment: revert to the original.